# Can I Use SetLOD with D3D9Ex?

Tags: directx9, level-of-detail, mipmaps

I need to limit the mipmap level loaded onto the device for certain textures, but I'm using a D3D9Ex-based engine, so I can only use `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT`, *not* `D3DPOOL_MANAGED`.

Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that I can use `SetLOD`

> for a managed texture.

Does that mean that I cannot use `SetLOD` in D3D9Ex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is no, you cannot use `SetLOD`.  As the documentation says, the texture must be [managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which means `D3DPOOL_MANAGED` and which [does not exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Direct3D 9Ex.

I have a sample app which uses Direct3D 9Ex, and tried calling `SetLOD`, and I got a return of `0` which means it failed according to the documentation which states

> This method returns 0 on nonmanaged textures